# Issue when sending Json post request with Enums in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, http-post

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 project. I tried to send a post request through the postman. But It hits the controller as a null value when My model has an enums data type.

I have a string enum

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    [StringValue("Payment")]
    Payment,

    [StringValue("Deferred")]
    Deferred,

    [StringValue("Refund")]
    Refund,

    [StringValue("Repeat")]
    Repeat,
}
```

And this is my request

```
{
  "transactionType": "Payment",  
   "amount": 1000
}
```

This is my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Payment([FromBody] PaymentRequest paymentRequest)
{
    var result = await _opayoPaymentService.PaymentTranscation(paymentRequest);
        
    return Ok(result);
}
```

This is my model class:

```
public class PaymentRequest
{
     public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }  // If I comment this The request is hitting fine otherwise It hit as null value,
     public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I guess my enums are wrong. Could anyone help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping in your controller will not be make on the `StringValue` meta but on the `int` type of the `enum`. And in your case Payment is 0, Deferred is 1 and so on. You can assign different values for them if you don't want to let the  framework to do it automatically for you. So instead of

> {
> "transactionType": "Payment",
> "amount": 1000
> }

use

> {
> "transactionType": 0,
> "amount": 1000
> }

Comment: could you please explain more. I did not get your point

Comment: Thank you, What should i do to send as  `"transactionType": "Payment" `

Comment: You will have to create a custom binder. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and inside a function that uses Enum.ToString  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=net-5.0) and map your string to the enum type.

Answer (score 0):

D A response is correct.
But if you want to be able to send the string value very easily, you just have to add:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum TransactionType
{
...
```

From Newtonsoft.Json;